# Having different material for 2 linked object

Tags: modeling, texturing

HI i have a sphere and **duplicate linked** it so now they're both are identical. Is it possible to link only for mesh changes ? for example i want these 2 sphere to have its own differnt material while they're both still keep updating itself when i edit the shape (edit mode).

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in the *Properties* panel > *Material* > In the dropdown menu, switch from *Data* to *Object*, now you can create a new material but the meshes are still linked.

[image]